# Retrieval of every entry from all different users from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
[image]

I have this firebase database
I want to retrive every entry of every user but i dont know the id of the user and the separate todo in an array.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Essentially fetch the whole database as per your DB structure? You can just fetch the root in that case `await get(ref(db))`

Comment: And then you can either get a specific child if you knows its name with `snapshot.child('completed')` or you can loop over all children (if you don't know their names) with `snapshot.forEach((child) => { ... })`.

Comment: What do you mean by *entry* what *entries* do you want? Also, which nodes represent the users? Are those user uid's? It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. You can export your Firebase structure from the Firebase console and include it as text. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)